# How to implement a firebase transaction

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, transactions

I have this schema in my firebase :[image]

I have a node articles under it have the ids of users, under one id I have a wishlist name then the articles and the wishlist info, So when I want to change the wishlist name I take the children of the node I want to change then I create w new one with the new name and the same children then I remove the old wishlist. So I want to create a transaction to do all the work in same time or not to do it at all if there is a bad connection because I can loose the data if the operation is interrupted. This is my current code and how I can put the operation in a firebase transaction. Thank you for your help !

```
func updateWishlist(wishlist:WishList,newName:String){
    if((reachability.connection == .wifi) || (reachability.connection == .cellular)){
        self.showProgressView()
        let child = self.ref.child("Articles").child((user!.uid)!)
        self.ref.child("Articles").child((user!.uid)!).child(wishlist.name) .updateChildValues(["name":newName]) { error, _ in
            if(error == nil){
                //create new node with new name
                let oldName=wishlist.name
                child.child(wishlist.name).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in self.ref.child("Articles").child((GlobalVar.user!.uid)!).child(newName).setValue(snapshot.value as! [String : Any]) { error, _ in
                        if(error == nil){
                            self.dismissHUD(isAnimated: true)
                            self.title=newName
                            self.showMessage("Wishlist modifier !", type: .success, options: [.position(.bottom)])
                        self.ref.child("Articles").child((GlobalVar.user!.uid)!).child(oldName).removeValue()

                        }
                        else{
                            self.dismissHUD(isAnimated: true)

                            print("update wishlist name transaction failed")
                        }
                    }
                    user?.wishLists[self.passedWishlistIndex!].name=newName
                })
            }
            self.dismissHUD(isAnimated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don’t include images or links in your questions. Include code and structures as text. That way, if we need to use it in an answer (like I did) I don't have to retype it! To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy and paste a snippet of your structure.

Comment: Hey Jay, Ok I get it, thank you for your clarification it will help me with my future posts.

Answer (score 1):

This issue really comes down to this statement

> I want to change the wishlist name I take the children (out) of the node I
>   want to change then I **create a new one with the new name** and the same
>   children then **I remove the old wishlist**

The fix is to *not use dynamic data as node keys*. Restructuring your data will eliminate the need for a transaction.

The wishlist name should be stored as a child of the node with a key created with *.childByAutoId*.

To clarify, your structure is *currently* this

```
Articles
   article_0
      dadoune //wish list name
      solo    //with list name
         articles
            xxx
            yyy
            zzz
   artical_1
   artical_2
```

and here's what will work; move the wish list name to a child node.

```
Articles
   article_0
      -Jk0ksk0kj9sdfsdf   //wish list key created with .childByAutoId
         wish_list_name: "dadoune"  //store the name as a child
      -Jyl909m9mm3o99jt   //wish list key created with .childByAutoId
         wish_list_name: "solo"  //store the name as a child
         articles
            xxx
            yyy
            zzz
   article_1
   article_2
```

By storing the dynamic wish list name as a child, you can simply change it whenever you want without having to read the node, delete the node, change the name, and re-write the node.

Comment: Hey Jay, thank you for your reply. Yes I know that the structure is wrong but I can't change it because there is already a lot of data saved in the database and a web application that already work with this structure. These are the problems when you continue working on an existing project.

Comment: @mark It should be straightforward to fix this once, otherwise you may have  ongoing issues. Craft an app to iterate over those nodes and correct the issue; here's two options. Using .childAdded, iterate over each child node, reading it in, creating a new proper node key and writing it back out with the wish list as a child. Update the app accordingly to use the child node. Second option is to copy all of the data to a new property formatted node, keeping both sets of data - perhaps App V1.0 and then V2.0 app that reads the new data. Once everyone has migrated to V2, delete the node.